# AddEventListener Invalid calling object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have the following snippet of code in which I try to implement a custom behavior for addEventListener:

```
var original = Element.prototype.addEventListener;

Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
    original(type, listener, options); // throws an error
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```

The code works correctly on Chrome and Firefox, but under IE 11 it through the following error: "SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object". Can the following code actually be done in IE or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var original = document.addEventListener;

Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, options) {
    original.bind(document, type, listener, options)();
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```

To be honest I don't understand the situation 100%, but obviously has something to do with the binding of the function. I came across a similar situation and solved it in a similar fashion. While researching I came across this SO. Sorry I'm a bit late. :-)

If anybody else can explain exactly what is going on here, that'd be great!